# UI Alternative to Populating and Importing Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc

General question here. I have a Spring Web MVC Application that allows users to enter data one record at a time. Validation checks are run when adding/editing each individual record (database calls, client side validation, etc)

We want to provide users a way to bulk insert many records on a single load. Right now the obvious choice is importing an excel spreadsheet, however I feel like this will require a **ton** of redundant work as we will have to provide all the same validation checks, dynamic string building, and preloading drop downs in this excel sheet as we have done in our application. Thus my question is, is there a simple solution of recreating this process via a web interface that would imitate entering data into a spreadsheet (Any tool or framework of sorts)? If this could be done on the front end we would be able to utilize all the functionality we have already implemented

Hope this isn't a poor question, I would just *really* like to avoid spreadsheets all together

Comment: Could you use javascript to build the layer on top of your preset application to bulk in the records and then stream through them through your existing flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use http://handsontable.com - it is a javascript component that I use.

You can get quite close to Excel-like behaviour, in a browser. You can also copy / paste to and from Excel with it.